# Editing a post for the blog, need some way to keep formatting for some long computer output

Tags: support, blog

After mixedmath tweaked something  I was able to post a draft on the BLOG. Going well now, the major problem is the giant blocks of computer output I have. On MSE Main, there is an editing option along the top {} for preformatted text and computer code. I'm afraid the blog button called "code" simply does not do the same thing. I want to run the mouse over 20 or 80 lines of output and say "format this all together, keep all lines separate." No luck so far.

Any ideas?

Oh, I made a jpeg of the edit window, you can see the code button:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in `<pre></pre>` tags in the "Text" tab (instead of "Visual").  For example, writing:

```
<pre>int main() {
   return 0;
}</pre>
```

...results in:

```
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
Interestingly enough, the `<code></code>` tags seem to auto-magically rearrange themselves to only highlight a *single* line.  The `<pre></pre>` tags avoid this issue.

Comment: It would have been better if I had known this before submitting the draft for review; still, I can repeat this at the blog room for mixedmath

Comment: @WillJagy You can still edit your post even after submitting for review.  (At least, you should be able to, if I recall correctly)

Comment: I think you are correct, but the "Save Draft" button has disappeared, so I think it better to leave it be while informing mixedmath of your pre stuff.

Comment: I always use `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>` on Wordpress...  belt with suspenders, but it works.